# What is the web-extensions folder in firebase JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

While exploring the `firebase` npm module, I encourtered a sub-path called `web-extensions`. What is the use for this sub-path? I understand that usual firebase auth doesn't work in web extensions due to content security policies, so is the `web-extensions` sub-path useful in such case? If yes, is there any doc/example about how to use it?

I tried replacing `firebase/auth` with `firebase/web-extension/auth` but seems like `signInWithPopup` is not n exported function there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From checking the release notes it seems that this directory was added in [version 10.8](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#authentication) to:

> Added a firebase/auth/web-extension entry point for web extension developers. This entry point does not include any code that loads remote scripts, which are disallowed under [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate#remotely-hosted-code). In extensions, this entry point should replace firebase/auth completely, and developers should not try to use both in the same app. See GitHub issue [#7617](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7617).

From reading that it seems related to Chrome extensions. That would also explain why `signInWithPopup` doesn't work, as you can't sign in with a popup in a Chrome extension as far as I know. You'll want to use `signInWithCredential` instead, as shown [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-js/auth/chromextension/readme/) (although that page has not been updated for the latest SDK release).

Comment: Thanks Frank. This did give some direction to explore more. Hopefully we'll have the docs added soon